# Convert column to header in a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52082853) with a solution not fully fitting my needs. And I do not understand all details of the solution their so I am not able to adapt it to my situation.

This is my initial dataframe where all unique values in the `Y` column should become a column.

```
   Y  P  v
0  A  X  0
1  A  Y  1
2  B  X  2
3  B  Y  3
4  C  X  4
5  C  Y  5
```

The result should look like this where `P` is the first column or it could be the `index` also. So `P` could be understood as a row heading. And the values from 'Y' are the column headings. And the values from `v` are in each cell now.

```
   P  A  B  C
0  X  0  2  4
1  Y  1  3  5
```

## Not working approach

This is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/52082963/4865723

```
new_index = ['Y', df.groupby('Y').cumcount()]
final = df.set_index(new_index)
final = final['P'].unstack('Y')
print(final)
```

The problem here is that the `index` (or first column) does not contain the values from `Y` and the `v` column is totally gone.

```
Y  A  B  C
0  X  X  X
1  Y  Y  Y
```

## My own unfinished idea

```
>>> df.groupby('Y').agg(list)
        P       v
Y
A  [X, Y]  [0, 1]
B  [X, Y]  [2, 3]
C  [X, Y]  [4, 5]
```

I do not know if this help or how to go further from this point on.

The full MWE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

# initial data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Y': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'P': list('XYXYXY'),
    'v': range(6)
})
print(df)


# final result I want
final = pd.DataFrame({
    'P': list('XY'),
    'A': [0, 1],
    'B': [2, 3],
    'C': [4, 5]
})
print(final)

# approach based on:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/52082963/4865723
new_index = ['Y', df.groupby('Y').cumcount()]
final = df.set_index(new_index)
final = final['P'].unstack('Y')
print(final)
```

Comment: This is a pivot: `df.pivot(index='P', columns='Y', values='v')`. Then you can chain on a `.reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)` to get the labeling consistent with your output, but the core part of this is the pivot.

Comment: The [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe) and the answers are much to complex and unfocused. To much questions in one. They do not help future readers.

Comment: 475 people have found that question useful, which is astonishing on SO. That question is well organized and literally covers many of the reshaping with clear to see inputs and outputs. It helps because people can actually learn about pivot, as opposed to the quality of answers posted here which are simply "use this code" (similar to my comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anything complex, this is a simple pivot:

```
df.pivot(index='P', columns='Y', values='v').reset_index()
```